# Squishy manufactured floors can they be fixed?

Tags: flooring

My brand new manufactured floors has squish boards when I walk.  Can this be fixed?

Comment: Do you mean floors in a manufactured home (aka a mobile home)?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info (e.g. what's the floor and subfloor made of?). And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.